# What is a quant?

Tags: 3d, game-engine, units-of-measurement

I am experimenting with gamestudio A8 and the unit used in the 3d world is quant.

My question is. how many quants is a meter?

I want to make some models in sketchup and I use meters there. I can convert the models to mdl.

The problem is. When animating and moving objects. I need to know how many quants there are in one meter.

I also want the sizes to match other models from the internet.

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question.

Comment: @Gabe: 'cause, as Nick answered, the "unit" here is a wholly arbitrary thing that exists only in *code* ...

Answer (score 7):

Like most 3D engines, there's no real world size to anything except what you decide. You might decide that a single unit is a metre, or a furlong, or a light year. A quant is just Gamestudio's name for one of these arbitrary units.

The MDL file format doesn't have real world units either, and models on the Internet will also be of varying scale. You'll just have to pick your favourite unit and resize anything that doesn't match.

Comment: @Aaron: There is a reasonable chance that each model-maker made it equal to some real world length unit. So look for something in the model whose "natural" size is known to you (the height of a character 4.5--6.5 feet or 1.5--2 meter), the length of a car (3-5 meters), etc... Then guess-n-check.

Answer (score -1):

I did some experiments with sketchup and gamestudio. And I found out that 1 meter in sketchup is 1 quant in gamestudio.

Comment: -1 sure, but that doesn't matter